# putty portforwarding mysql windows

Tags: linux, windows, macos, ssh, putty

I have a problem with connecting to remote mysql with putty through ssh with port forwarding.

```
remote: ubuntu 14.04
remote ip address: 1.1.1.1
remote port of mysql: 3306
local: windows 7
```

This works when i enable a tunnel in putty with following config

```
source port: 3306
destination: 127.0.0.1:3306
user: root (all privileges enabled)
```

With this config, i can connect with workbench to localhost:3306

But strangely when i change the config like this

```
source port: 3306
destination: 127.0.0.1:3307
user: root (all privileges enabled)
```

I can't connect with workbench  on localhost:3307. I get an 10061 error (can't connect to MySQL on '127.0.0.1')

I want to change the port because I need to run a mysql instance on local windows.

With mac 10.10, i have no problem connecting to remote mysql, with following ssh command:

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1 -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -N or ssh root@1.1.1.1 -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

With mac, i can connect with workbench on both ports.

I have tried changing ports in putty, but it seems to be a problem with mysql or windows.

Maybe something important, have an autossh agent running from another server to this remote server for replication.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was installing [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), i can now execute the same command of my mac on my windows machine.